# Haskell - Compare two list of strings and return the number of times a word appears?

Tags: haskell

I am a beginner in Haskell. I am trying to find a solution to how to compare two lists of strings and check how many times the words of one list appear in the other list.

I have attempted to use the `length` function but it returns the number of string (elements) in the list. I also used `filter` but I am unsure how to construct this solution. I have checked [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-List.html) website for help but I am unsure which function to use and how.

For example, the below code should return the number 2 as *listofStrings* contains 2 words form *animals*.

```
animals = ["cat", "dog", "rabbit"]
listofStrings = ["the", "cat", "bit", "the" , "dog"]
```

Expected result should be:

```
2
```

Comment: Can you describe (without Haskell) how the algorithm would look like? For instance by writing it in pseudo-code, or another programming laguage?

Comment: **1.** create two lists of strings as shown above **2.** check second list with first list **3.** count how many times the words from the first list appear in the second list and then return the number

Comment: Have you looked anywhere on [hoogle?](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Eq+a+%3D%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5Ba%5D) There's a function there that might help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter f`, where `f :: a -> Bool`, on a list of `a`s, and return only those elements `x` for which `f x` is `True`.

Thus, taking `f` to be `(== x)` above, gives you a list consisting only of `x`s, repeated the number of times `x` occurs in the original list.

Composing this with `length` then gives you how many times `x` occurs in the list:

```
countOccurencesIn xs x = length . filter (== x) $ xs
```

Then you want to call this with your second list as `xs` for each `x` in your first list, which is a `map`:

```
map (countOccurencesIn ys) xs
```

This gives you a list of integers resulting from replacing each element of `xs` by the number of its occurences in `ys`, then you should of course sum these numbers:

```
finalCounter xs ys = sum . map (countOccurencesIn ys) $ xs
```

Answer (score 0):

If your lists dont have duplicates, you can use [`intersect`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=intersect) from `Data.List` to do this task:

```
import Data.List

countWords :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Int
countWords xs ys = length $ intersect xs ys
```

Which works as follows:

```
*Main> countWords ["the", "cat", "bit", "the" , "dog"] ["cat", "dog", "rabbit"] 
2
```

But runs into problems when list one has duplicates:

```
*Main> countWords ["the", "cat", "bit", "the" , "dog", "cat"] ["cat", "dog", "rabbit"]
2
```

The above function should have returned `3`. One way around this is the recursive approach. We can first make a function which filters elements from list one, which exist in list two:

```
filterWords :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
filterWords [] _ = []
filterWords (x:xs) ys
   | x `elem` ys = x : filterWords xs ys
   | otherwise = filterWords xs ys
```

which works as follows:

```
*Main> filterWords ["the", "cat", "bit", "the" , "dog", "cat"] ["cat", "dog", "rab
bit"]
["cat","dog","cat"]
```

Then we can just take the `length` of this result:

```
countWords :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Int
countWords xs ys = length $ filterWords xs ys
```

Which now works properly:

```
*Main> countWords ["the", "cat", "bit", "the" , "dog", "cat"] ["cat", "dog", "rabbit"]
3
```

As others have mentioned, `filter` makes this task much easier:

```
countWords :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Int
countWords xs ys = length $ filter (\x -> x `elem` ys) xs
```